# Xcode - 7.3 Ceating a iOS Universal Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, ios-universal-framework

I am trying to create a iOS universal framework which is built with universal architecture.
I followed this Link to create an Universal Framework - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/12/13/building-a-universal-framework-for-ios/

In this they have clearly mentioned how headers should be added, but didn't mention where to keep function definitions ?
As already Resources directory is present do I need to place all function definition in that ?

Comment: Function definitions should be located _in_ your header files. Do you mean function implementations?

Comment: yes i have a library called "libzip" but that is built in single architecture , so i have its all .h files and .c files i.e heads and its implementations.

Comment: 2020, You can safely use this script for creating Universal iOS Frameworks: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework